# How to match a string with a value in a database

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite, passwords

*I think value would be the correct word.  Please edit if not.*

**Contents:**

**Problem 1(String not staying permanently in database)**

**Problem 2(Idea for problem 1)**

I'm creating a program which adds a string into a table in a database using Sqlite3 in Python3.  I am using a function which asks you for the password.  Later, wanting to recall the function if the inputted string equals something in the database.(If it does not equal anything in the database, then we insert it into the passwords table.)

**Problem 1:**

The problem is that when I stop running the program and run it again, the string does not stay in the database which leads it to allowing me to retype previous passwords.  What I **want** the program to do is to make the string stay in the database after stopping it.
**Here is the program for the paragraph above:(SCROLL DOWN** for an idea for problem 1 **)**

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib

db  = sqlite3.connect( "users.db" )
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passwords( pwd TEXT, UNIQUE( pwd ))" )

def password():
  pwd = input( "password: " )
  sha = hashlib.sha256( pwd.encode( 'utf-8' )).hexdigest()
  cur.execute( "INSERT INTO passwords VALUES( ? )", ( sha, ))

while True:
  try:
    password()
    #break
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print( "aborted" )
    break
  except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print( "cannot reuse that password" )
db.commit()
db.close()
```

======================================================================
**Problem 2:** (Idea for Problem 1)

Here is an updated version.  What I am doing here is trying to add the string into the database's table if it does or doesn't match with any of the strings.  the error I am having here is that pwd is not a variable on line 13 although I do have it as one and had set it as a global variable.  If wanting to help on this problem, i'd like to know why pwd isn't a variable and how to make it one.

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib

db  = sqlite3.connect( "used_passwords.db" )
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passwords( pwd TEXT, UNIQUE( pwd ))" )

def password():
  global pwd
  pwd = input( "password: " ) #turn this into a global variable
  sha = hashlib.sha256( pwd.encode( 'utf-8' )).hexdigest()
  cur.execute( "INSERT INTO passwords VALUES( ? )", ( sha, ))

while True:
  #take pwd from password and put it here
  sha = hashlib.sha256( pwd.encode( 'utf-8' )).hexdigest()
  try:
    password()
    #break
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print( "aborted" )
    break
  except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print( "cannot reuse that password" )
    cur.execute( "INSERT INTO passwords VALUES( ? )", ( sha, ))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **problem 1** move your `db.commit()` into the loop, either into an `else` for your `try-except` or into the `password()` function directly.

```
try:
  password()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print( "aborted" )
  break
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
  print( "cannot reuse that password" )
else:
  db.commit()
```

or

```
def password():
  pwd = input( "password: " )
  sha = hashlib.sha256( pwd.encode( 'utf-8' )).hexdigest()
  cur.execute( "INSERT INTO passwords VALUES( ? )", ( sha, ))
  db.commit()
```

Commit your inserts individually after they succeed or you risk losing all of them in an unhandled error. I do not see any other reason for your passwords to "not stay in the database" than uncommitted inserts.

As for **problem 2**: when the program enters the loop, `password()` has not yet been called, hence `pwd` does not yet exist when you try to use it.

```
while True:
  #take pwd from password and put it here
  sha = hashlib.sha256( pwd.encode( 'utf-8' )).hexdigest()  # <-- pwd is undefined here ...
try:
    password()  # ... because it needs this to be executed at least once
```

Why even do the `hashlib.sha256` for a second time in the loop? You already do it in `password`; you can remove that line from the loop and get rid of the `NameError` immedietaly. Also, the second INSERT in the loop's `except` block does not make sense. If the INSERT violates the UNIQUE constraint and raises the `IntegrityError` you attempt that very same INSERT again? This will raise the same error, which is unhandled this time and will make your programm crash.

Stick with your first approach, it is a lot better. Don't use global variables unless you really *really* **REALLY** have to.